# Jenkins email notification is not working

Tags: shell, email, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I just wanted to send an email from Jenkins Editable email notification. I want the output as table format. In Editable notification, there is an option to give Content Type is html and input html tags.

I configured everything. but when I triggered the build it says 'No emails triggered'. Not sure what could be the error. Does anyone have any idea? also please let me know how to send emails with table(it would be in body of email) in shell scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should click the

> "Advanced setting" button ==> Add Trigger, and then choose something like "Always".